# What's the most reliable way to determine an OpenStack host's own UUID?

Tags: openstack, rackspace

I would like to be able to reliably determine the UUID associated with an OpenStack guest from within the guest.  A klugey way to do it would be something like:

```
# nova show `hostname` | grep ' id '
| id                                   | 10493365-870f-4ff1-86ed-500b4b8db814                                 |
```

However, the hostname that a system knows itself as would not necessarily be the hostname that OpenStack knows the guest as.

Is there a way do do what I want?  BTW, I'd actually be running this at Rackspace.

Comment: Is this on the Rackspace Public Cloud or a Rackspace OpenStack Private Cloud?

Comment: Rackspace Public

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `xenstore-read name`. This asks the hypervisor for the instance's name.

```
# xenstore-read name
instance-10493365-870f-4ff1-86ed-500b4b8db814
```

I refer to [this page](http://www.syntheticworks.com/rackspace-cloud/linux-rackspace-cloud/all-about-nova-agent-linux/) frequently, specifically the section "XenStore commands to be run on guest VM".